# BibTeX error: "You're missing an entry type"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a very simple document `report.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

AlexNet \cite{krizhevsky2012imagenet} is great

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And a very simple `.bib` file `references.bib`:

```tex
@article{krizhevsky2012imagenet,
  title={Imagenet classification with deep convolutional neural networks},
  author={Krizhevsky, Alex and Sutskever, Ilya and Hinton, Geoffrey E},
  journal={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  volume={25},
  year={2012}
}
```

When I compile with `pdflatex report.tex`, I get the following warnings, and the references don't render properly:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `krizhevsky2012imagenet' on page 1 undefined on input l
ine 5.

No file report.bbl.
...
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

[image]

The command `pdflatex report.tex` produces an output file `report.aux`. If I run the command `bibtex report.aux`, I get the following output:

```
...
Database file #1: references.bib
You're missing an entry type---line 1 of file references.bib
 :  ■@
 :    article{krizhevsky2012imagenet,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "krizhevsky2012imagenet"
(There was 1 error message)
```

Why am I getting this error message, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the file `references.bib` was using an unusual text encoding, apparently called "UTF-16 LE" (according to my VS Code IDE). I switched to "UTF-8" text encoding, and now everything works nicely again.

How did I end up with this unusual encoding? Well, in the absence of the `touch` command in Powershell, I had created the file `references.bib` using the Powershell command `echo "" >> references.bib`. When I opened this file up in VS Code, VS Code interpreted the file to be in "UTF-16 LE", and when I pasted in the BiBTeX reference, VS Code converted that reference to match the text encoding of the file. But `bibtex` apparently didn't recognise this unusual text encoding. Took me a while (and some metaphorical banging of my head against the wall) before figuring that one out.

EDIT: I added `touch` to Powershell by adding `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to the system `PATH` environment variable. Now I can `touch` files and they get interpreted as UTF-8. No more UTF-16 LE for me :-)